# transition css property making content to see twice

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

[image]- when i click section 2 section 2 content opens.

- when i click section 2 content back it closes but when it closes i see text two times.
- when section 2 body is about to close i see section 2 content in black color but green background is dissappeared
- i debugged the code I think its happeing due to the transition css property, I can't remove it since I need to see a smooth close.

**transition: height .5s;
    transition: height .5s, padding-top .5s, padding-bottom .5s;**

- can you tell me how to fix it.
- providing my code in the fiddle.

```or-tag-here
.accordion-section {
    border-bottom: solid 1px #000;
}

.accordion-section > h3 {
    padding: 6px;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: #CCC;
    margin: 0;
}


.accordion-section > .body {
    height: 0;
    padding: 0 10px;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    transition: height .5s;
    transition: height .5s, padding-top .5s, padding-bottom .5s;
}
```

Comment: Did the answer below help?

Comment: @AlanDunning thanks for your reply...I have added image now...after green background disappears still I see the section 1 content text...I wanted to get it disappeared at the same time green background disappears

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to `hide` that `text` which appears on all `section` after `accordion close`, so for that set the text `color` as `transparent` which initially `merges` with `background-color` as below.

```
.accordion-section > .body {
    height: 0;
    padding: 0 10px;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    color:transparent;/*Add this*/
    transition: height .5s, padding-top .5s, padding-bottom .5s;
}
```

Comment: it worked...thanks...I have one more question if I click section 1 section 1 content opens, if I click section section2 section 1 content closes, next scenario if I click section 1 again section 1  content opens where as now if I click section 4 section 1 content does not close...can you tell me how to fix it...

Comment: I will check that, but first see this jsFiddle if you don't want to make text-color as transparent then there are 2 places where you have to add transition http://jsfiddle.net/b4L6kyg4/88/

Comment: @texirv section 4 can't close section 1 as they are 2 different accordions.

Comment: is there any way where we can make code changes...to achieve it :(

Comment: No @texirv till what I know, might be I'm wrong on that, so post a new question, surely someone should guide you on that issue.

Comment: and this fiddle  jsfiddle.net/b4L6kyg4/88  not working...only color transparent working properly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143064/discussion-between-frnt-and-texi-rv).

Comment: hey, when we expand transition is smooth but when we collapse transition is not good...when its about to collapse I see a shake...I play with transition...nut its not working can you help me

Answer (score 2):

Based on the fiddle you provided it looks like you are doing css based animations on the hiding and showing of the section content you mentioned. However, you do not seem to be defining the things that you want animating, or at least not all of the ones you want animating.

You could replace:

`transition: height .5s, padding-top .5s, padding-bottom .5s;`

with

`transition: line-height .5s, margin-bottom .5s, color .5s, font-size .5s, background .5s, height .5s, padding .5s;`

However, as you seem to be animating all the current styles of the section and its content you could simply use:

`transition: all .5s;`

Here is that change applied to your fiddle:

[Updated fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/b4L6kyg4/85/)

Comment: thanks for your reply...I have added image now...after green background disappears still I see the section 1 content text...I wanted to get it disappeared at the same time green background disappears